# How to find attendee details of a particular Order in Eventbrite API

Tags: webhooks, eventbrite

When I implemented (4 months ago) the Eventbrite API integration into my application, I got the response along with attendee details for an order's request (that is, **https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/orders/454268667/?token=SXXXX.....XXX**).

But today, I checked the response of an order's request but I did not get the attendee details and the ticket_class_id. Have they changed the API response formats? How to get the attendee details & ticket_class_id of an order?

I need to solve this issue in production server.

Now I get response like this (without attendee details & ticket_class_id).

```
{
    "resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/orders/454268667/", 
    "id": "454268667", 
    "changed": "2015-09-11T09:34:03Z", 
    "created": "2015-09-11T09:34:02Z", 
    "costs": {
        "payment_fee": {
            "currency": "USD", 
            "display": "$0.00", 
            "value": 0
        }, 
        "gross": {
            "currency": "USD", 
            "display": "$0.00", 
            "value": 0
        }, 
        "eventbrite_fee": {
            "currency": "USD", 
            "display": "$0.00", 
            "value": 0
        }, 
        "tax": {
            "currency": "USD", 
            "display": "$0.00", 
            "value": 0
        }, 
        "base_price": {
            "currency": "USD", 
            "display": "$0.00", 
            "value": 0
        }
    }, 
    "name": "Breen Ho", 
    "first_name": "Breen", 
    "last_name": "Ho", 
    "email": "breenXXX@gmail.com", 
    "status": "placed", 
    "time_remaining": null, 
    "event_id": "18568926158"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out our Expansion Framework: http://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/reference/expansions/

You can add a parameter that says "expand=attendees", and then you'll get the related attendee objects.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a ton Mitch.. It works fine now.. Thanks a lot.. :) :)

Comment: how to get attendees for `owned_events` ? url I tried was "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/owned_events/?expand=event.attendees" and "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/owned_events/?expand=attendees"

Comment: I can't get this to work for owned_events either - have raised a seperate question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138837/eventbrite-api-doesnt-expand-attendees - did you ever get it to work?

Comment: The link has changed, it is now: https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api#/introduction/expansions