# Eventbrite API doesn't expand attendees

Tags: php, eventbrite

Using PHP to hook into the Eventbrite API

Going to https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/owned_events/?token=XXX&expand=ticket_classes works and `ticket_classes` is expanded

However when I use https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/owned_events/?token=XXX&expand=ticket_classes,attendees then `attendees` is not expanded but it shown under `EXPANDED FIELDS`

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the `/events/{event_id}/attendees/`

```
curl -X GET   https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/{event_id}/attendees/   -H 'Authorization: Bearer PERSONAL_OAUTH_TOKEN'
```

Read more in the docs: https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/docs/attendees